# How does .call in javascript work?

Tags: javascript

I have seen this code on the MDN site:

```
01  function Product(name, value){
02     this.name = name;
03     if(value >= 1000)
04        this.value = 999;
05     else
06        this.value = value;
07  }
08   
09  function Prod_dept(name, value, dept){
10     this.dept = dept;
11     Product.call(this, name, value);
12  }
13   
14  Prod_dept.prototype = new Product();
15   
16  // since 5 is less than 1000, value is set
17  cheese = new Prod_dept("feta", 5, "food");
18   
19  // since 5000 is above 1000, value will be 999
20  car = new Prod_dept("honda", 5000, "auto");
```

It says you can use call to chain constructors. I have some questions:

1) Why is line 14 called why would we add it to the prototype and why would that mean that Product is called when we create Prod_dept?

2) What does line 11 mean? How is this related to the prototype?

3) What is line 20 meant to show us?

Answer (score 5):

1) Setting an instance of `Product` as the prototype object for `Prod_dept` adds the values and methods of that `Product` instance (and its prototype) to the prototype chain of all your `Prod_dept` instances.

It also allows `instanceof` to show that an object created from `Product_dept` is an instance of both constructors

```
var a = new Product();
var b = new Product_dept();

a instanceof Product       // true
a instanceof Product_dept  // false

b instanceof Product       // true
b instanceof Product_dept  // true
```

2) Because `this` is the new object being constructed by `Prod_dept`, the `.call` lets you set that object as the `this` value of the `Product` method, so that whatever the `Product` method does with `this` will be done on that new `Prod_dept` instance (in this case, running the code for adding values to `name` and `value` properties).

3) It just creates a new instance from the `Prod_dept` constructor.

Overall, this is one pattern for using JavaScript's *prototypal inheritance* mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

The code is simply demonstrating prototypal inheritance in JavaScript.

1) What the code is saying on line 14 is that you want your `Prod_dept` Function to inherit the properties and characteristics of the base `Product` Function.

Every function in JavaScript has a prototype property and it contains an object that you can add methods and properties to.

Prototype is a special property that gets created as soon as you define the function. Its initial value is an empty object {} but can be overwritten to allow you to define your own methods or inherit those from another Function.

2) Line 10 is simply assigning a property to your `Prod_dept` Function the value being provided by the dept argument being passed through the constructor.

3) Line 14 is allowing you to apply the other two arguments "name, value" to your base `Product` function but in the context of your `Prod_dept` Function. Further information on that method can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call).

Answer (score 0):

1) Line 14 makes Prod_dept inherit the Dept object - anytime you instantiate a Prod_dept, it uses Dept as the base object.

2) Line 10 simply stores the words "auto" and "food" in the .dept attribute of the object.

3) Line 20: When Prod_dept is instantiated, JS will instantiate a Dept object as well, and that constructor (Line 1) restricts the `value` parameter to be 999 at most (lines 3-6)

Comment: This is very similar to inheritance in javascript. So whats the overall difference?

Comment: JS doesn't have explicit "object X extends object Y" syntax, so this is one of the accepted methods of doing inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Uses prototypical inheritance - prod_dept inherits from Product. More info if you google "prototypical inheritance".

2) It is what the constructor does - initialising the "dept" member.

3) Together with the comment above it, it just shows that all constructors will be called, so they are really chained.

I think your questions miss the point a little. The magic about call is that the first parameter will be "this" in the called function - if you use it on a constructor, the contructor will act on whatever you passed in as the first parameter to call - this way you can use a constructor on whatever you want because you "fake it" to work on an arbitrary object.

Comment: Hi Steven so whats the point in calling .call is it just so you can 'stuff' a reference from the calling method without having to account for it in the 'called method' signature?

Comment: The special catch is that the "reference" you "stuff in" will be the magical "this", which you cannot set by just using a function parameter. Learning what "this" does and how it behaves in javascript is one of the most important things to learn about js, and "call" and "apply" are the tools to modify "this".

Comment: Besides, don't take my word for it (or the msn's word), but rather Douglas Crockfords word: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html